# P2P file transfer by TIdtrivialftp

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, indy10

I am transferring files over LAN using Tidtrivialftpserver and Tidtrivialftp. I tried the example code and is working fine but Tidtrivialftpserver just starts writing file ,i want to implement a savedialog box so that i can save it on my desired location.i tried following but it writes file in the current directory. Also i am not convinced with this line (AStream := FS) in serverWriteFile because when i debug this code Astream gives nil but still it writes file. How?

```
var 
  file1: string;
  FS: tfilestream;

procedure TForm2.saveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if savedialog1.Execute then
  begin
   savedialog1.FileName:= file1;
    FS := TFileStream.Create(FileName,
    fmCreate or fmShareExclusive);
  end;
end;   

procedure TForm2.serverWriteFile(Sender: TObject; var FileName: string;
  const PeerInfo: TPeerInfo; var GrantAccess: Boolean; var AStream: TStream;
  var FreeStreamOnComplete: Boolean);
begin
  try
    Memo1.Lines.Add('started writing files...');
    file1 := ExtractFileName(Filename);
    { Open file in WRITE ONLY mode }
    //  FS := TFileStream.Create(FileName,
    //  fmCreate or fmShareExclusive);
    { Copy all the data }
    AStream := FS;
    { Set parameters }
    FreeStreamOnComplete := True;
    GrantAccess := True;
  except
    { On errors, deny access }
    GrantAccess := False;
    if Assigned(FS) then
    FreeAndNil(FS);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `OnWriteFile` event is to ask for permission to receive a file (`GrantAccess`, which is True by default) AND to obtain a `TStream` to receive the file data into (`AStream`, which is nil by default). `TIdTrivialFTPServer` cannot receive the data until the event handler exits first.  If you do not provide a `TStream`, but do set/leave `GrantAccess` to True, `TIdTrivialFTPServer` will create its own `TFileStream` internally using the current `FileName`.  So if you do not want to receive the file, you must set `GrantAccess` to False. If you want to prompt the user, you must do so inside of the `OnWriteFile` event handler (which is only safe to do directly if the `TIdTrivialFTPServer.ThreadEvent` property is False, otherwise you need to sync with the main thread to do the prompt safely), eg:

```
procedure TForm2.serverWriteFile(Sender: TObject; var FileName: string;
  const PeerInfo: TPeerInfo; var GrantAccess: Boolean; var AStream: TStream;
  var FreeStreamOnComplete: Boolean);
begin
  SaveDialog1.FileName := ExtractFileName(FileName);
  if SaveDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    // let TIdTrivialFTPServer create the TFileStream internally...
    FileName := SaveDialog1.FileName;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('started writing file...');
  end else
    GrantAccess := False;
end;
```

Comment: yes thanks a lot it is the right way but i want to perform save dialog on save button click (as file received save button becomes visible) , but by this method a dialog will appear by itself.

Comment: You are missing the point. When the server gets a new request to receive a file, it fires the `OnWriteFile` event to find out WHERE it can save the file. The only way you can prompt separately is if you receive the file to a temp file or memory stream first, then prompt, then move the temp file/memory to the chosen destination after it has fully uploaded. That is much more work then simply prompting in the `OnWriteFile` event before the upload is allowed to begin.